# About an equalizer-related property

Tags: category-theory

I have encountered a lemma in a book as follows.

> Given the diagram
>
> [image]
>
> Assume that:
>
> (i) $e$ makes equal $f$ and $g$;
>
> (ii) in the commutative diagram below the top and bottom composite
> morphisms are identity.
>
> [image]
>
> Then, $e$ is the equalizer of $f$ and $g$.

I know that equalizer definition requires the existence of a mediator morphism, as below,

[image]

such that $h = e \circ m$. But I don't know how to relate the lemma's assumptions to this definition. In particular, from (ii), we have

$$e \circ p \circ e = q \circ g \circ e = id_{C}.$$

So, $e$ may be written as

$$e  = p^{-1} \circ e^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ q^{-1}.$$

From (i), we also have

$$e  = f^{-1} \circ q^{-1}.$$

But, I don't see how these give rise to any conclusion about $m$.

Can one clarify this case?

Comment: You need to use $p$ and/or $q$ to get $m$ from $h$. Assume you have $m$ and $h = e \circ m$. Then $p \circ h = p \circ e \circ m = m$. What happens if you define $m = p \circ h$ – can you derive that $h = e \circ m$ as needed?

Comment: @ZhenLin: I think so, like $p \circ h = p \circ e \circ m = e^{-1} \circ m$. Then, $h = p^{-1} \circ e^{-1} \circ m = (e \circ p)^{-1} \circ m = e \circ m$. Can you explain how one should know that the starting point is $m = p \circ h$, not anything, for example, related to $q$?

Comment: There are some problems with what you wrote. For one thing, $e$ and $p$ are not necessarily invertible, so you don't have $e^{-1}$ or $p^{-1}$; for another, you don't "know" that $h = e \circ m$ yet so you can't use it in your proof. The "reason" why you should look at $p$ first is because you can compose $p$ and $h$ but you can't compose $q$ and $h$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: So, I did like $e \circ m = e \circ p \circ h = q \circ f \circ h = q \circ g \circ h$. But I don't see why $h = q \circ g \circ h$. Have I missed any step in between?

Comment: Very good. The last step is to remember that $q \circ g = \textrm{id}$ by hypothesis.